Github Action Go build caching modules for docker image build
I am running into issues with the caching of the go modules being downloaded everytime I run my github action. I have been trying to store a cache between each build of the application but it seems each time it builds on GA it downloads the modules everytime.
Dockerfile
FROM golang:1.23.2 AS builder

WORKDIR /app
COPY go.mod go.sum ./
RUN go mod download
COPY . .
ENV GOCACHE=/root/.cache/go-build
RUN --mount=type=cache,target="/root/.cache/go-build" \
    CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -v -o main ./src/

FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /app/main .
CMD ["./main"]


deploy.yml
name: Build and Deploy

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - 'main'

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    timeout-minutes: 10
    permissions:
      contents: read
      packages: write

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Go
        uses: actions/setup-go@v5
        with:
          go-version: "1.23.2"

      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v3
        with:
          version: latest
          driver-opts: |
            image=moby/buildkit:latest

      - name: Login to Github container Registry
        uses: docker/login-action@v3
        with:
          registry: ghcr.io
          username: ${{ github.actor }}
          password: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

      - name: Build and push Docker image
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v5
        with:
          context: .
          file: docker/Dockerfile
          push: true
          tags: |
            ghcr.io/org/app:latest
            ghcr.io/org/app:${{ github.sha }}
          platforms: linux/amd64
          cache-from: type=registry,ref=ghcr.io/org/app:latest
          cache-to: type=inline

  deploy:
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    timeout-minutes: 10
    if: "!contains(github.event.head_commit.message, '[skip deploy]')"

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Deploy to Server
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
          username: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
          key: ${{ secrets.SSH_KEY }}
          script_stop: true
          script: |
            cd /path/to/app/docker
            git pull origin main
            echo ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} | docker login ghcr.io -u ${{ github.actor }} --password-stdin
            docker compose down --remove-orphans
            docker network prune -f
            docker compose pull
            docker compose up -d


I am truly stumped as to why my build is not caching the modules. I have tried quite a few different things and can not seem to lower the build time on any subsequent builds of the application.
I am expecting the subsequent builds to be greatly reduced in time such that it does not re-fetch and download all the modules for my GO application. I have tried several different cache strategies, none change it. If I am doing it wrong I truly would appreciate some guidance.
